# JTable with autoscroll, problems when updating the cells

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, autoscroll

I have a table (JTable) of values which is updated in real time about every 10 seconds (last 2 columns out of 4 updated, for each row). I want this table to continuous scroll up so I used the example from:

http://wiki.byte-welt.net/wiki/MarqueePanelV

The scrolling wraps around, first line is shown after last line and works fine except one thing:

When I do the update of the DefaultTableModel (I'm using setValueAt() function), the values are printed at their original position (like the table is not scrolled). Only the portion with the 2 columns is refreshed, created some fracture in the view. The view is corrected at the next scroll (in 100 milliseconds) but is still visible on the screen. More, since I'm stopping the scroll when mouse is over the table, the update will create a visible fracture in the table view.

Any idea on how can I fix this problem?

Here is a code example showing the problem:

```
package scrollingtable;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

class MarqueePanelV extends JPanel
                       implements ActionListener, AncestorListener, WindowListener {
    private boolean paintChildren;
    private boolean scrollingPaused;
    private int scrollOffset;
    private int wrapOffset;
    private int preferredHeight = -1;
    private int scrollAmount;
    private int scrollFrequency;
    private boolean wrap = false;
    private int wrapAmount = 0;
    private boolean scrollWhenFocused = true;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(100, this);

    /**
     *  Convenience constructor that sets both the scroll frequency and
     *  scroll amount to a value of 5.
     */
    public MarqueePanelV() {
        this(20, 1);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param scrollFrequency
     * @param scrollAmount
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("LeakingThisInConstructor")
    public MarqueePanelV(int scrollFrequency, int scrollAmount) {
        setScrollFrequency(scrollFrequency);
        setScrollAmount(scrollAmount);
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        addAncestorListener(this);
    }

    /*
     *  Translate the location of the children before they are painted so it
     *  appears they are scrolling bottom to top
     */
    @Override
    public void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
        //  Need this so we don't see a flicker of the text before scrolling

        if (!paintChildren) {
            return;
        }
        int x = super.getPreferredSize().height;

        //  Normal painting as the components scroll bottom to top

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate(0, -scrollOffset);
        super.paintChildren(g);
        g2d.translate(0, scrollOffset);

        //  Repaint the start of the components on the bottom edge of the panel once
        //  all the components are completely visible on the panel.
        //  (Its like the components are in two places at the same time)

        if (isWrap()) {
            //wrapOffset = scrollOffset - super.getPreferredSize().height - wrapAmount;
            wrapOffset = scrollOffset - x - wrapAmount;
            g2d.translate(0, -wrapOffset);
            super.paintChildren(g);
            g2d.translate(0, wrapOffset);
        }
    }

    /*
     *  The default preferred size will be half the size of the components added to
     *  the panel. This will allow room for components to be scrolled on and off
     *  the panel.
     *
     *  The default height can be overriden by using the setPreferredHeight() method.
     */
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();

        d.height = (preferredHeight == -1) ? d.height / 2 : preferredHeight;

        return d;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return preferredHeight;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the preferred height on the panel. A value of -1 will cause the
     *  default preferred with size calculation to be used.
     *
     *  @param preferredHeight  preferred height of the panel in pixels
     */
    public void setPreferredHeight(int preferredHeight) {
        this.preferredHeight = preferredHeight;
        revalidate();
    }

    /**
     *  Get the scroll amount.
     *
     *  @return the scroll amount in pixels
     */
    public int getScrollAmount() {
        return scrollAmount;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the scroll amount. The number of pixels to scroll every time
     *  scrolling is done.
     *
     *  @param scrollAmount  scroll amount in pixels
     */
    public void setScrollAmount(int scrollAmount) {
        this.scrollAmount = scrollAmount;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the scroll frequency.
     *
     *  @return the scroll frequency
     */
    public int getScrollFrequency() {
        return scrollFrequency;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the scroll frequency. That is the number of times scrolling
     *  should be performed every second.
     *
     *  @param scrollFrequency  scroll frequency
     */
    public void setScrollFrequency(int scrollFrequency) {
        this.scrollFrequency = scrollFrequency;

        int delay = 1000 / scrollFrequency;
        timer.setInitialDelay(delay);
        timer.setDelay(delay);
    }

    /**
     *  Get the scroll only when visible property.
     *
     *  @return the scroll only when visible value
     */
    public boolean isScrollWhenFocused() {
        return scrollWhenFocused;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the scrolling property for unfocused windows.
     *
     *  @param scrollWhenVisible  when true scrolling pauses when the window
     *                                loses focus. Scrolling will continue when
     *                                the window regains focus. When false
     *                                scrolling is continuous unless the window
     *                                is iconified.
     */
    public void setScrollWhenFocused(boolean scrollWhenFocused) {
        this.scrollWhenFocused = scrollWhenFocused;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the wrap property.
     *
     *  @return the wrap value
     */
    public boolean isWrap() {
        return wrap;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the wrapping property. Normal scrolling is such that all the text
     *  will scroll from bottom to top. When the last part of the text scrolls off
     *  the bottom edge scrolling will start again from the bottom edge. Therefore
     *  there is a time when the component is blank as nothing is displayed.
     *  Wrapping implies that as the end of the text scrolls off the top edge
     *  the beginning of the text will scroll in from the bottom edge. So the end
     *  and the start of the text is displayed at the same time.
     *
     *  @param wrap  when true the start of the text will scroll in from the bottom
     *                edge while the end of the text is still scrolling off the top
     *                edge. Otherwise the panel must be clear of text before it
     *                will begin again from the bottom edge.
     */
    public void setWrap(boolean wrap) {
        this.wrap = wrap;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the wrap amount.
     *
     *  @return the wrap amount value
     */
    public int getWrapAmount() {
        return wrapAmount;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the wrapping amount. This specifies the space between the end of the
     *  text on the top edge and the start of the text from the bottom edge when
     *  wrapping is turned on.
     *
     *  @param wrapAmount  the amount in pixels
     */
    public void setWrapAmount(int wrapAmount) {
        this.wrapAmount = wrapAmount;
    }

    /**
     *  Start scrolling the components on the panel. Components will start
     *  scrolling from the bottom edge towards the top edge.
     */
    public void startScrolling() {
        paintChildren = true;
        scrollOffset = -getSize().height;

        timer.start();
    }

    /**
     *  Stop scrolling the components on the panel. The conponents will be
     *  cleared from the view of the panel
     */
    public void stopScrolling() {
        timer.stop();
        paintChildren = false;
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     *  The components will stop scrolling but will remain visible
     */
    public void pauseScrolling() {
        if (timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.stop();
            scrollingPaused = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     *  The components will resume scrolling from where scrolling was stopped.
     */
    public void resumeScrolling() {
        if (scrollingPaused) {
            timer.restart();
            scrollingPaused = false;
        }
    }


    /**
     *  Adjust the offset of the components on the panel so it appears that
     *  they are scrolling from bottom to top.
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        scrollOffset += scrollAmount;
        int height = super.getPreferredSize().height;

        if (scrollOffset > height) {
            scrollOffset = isWrap() ? wrapOffset + scrollAmount : -getSize().height;
        }
        //System.out.println("scroll offset: " + scrollOffset);

        repaint();
    }

    /**
     *  Get notified when the panel is added to a Window so we can use a
     *  WindowListener to automatically start the scrolling of the components.
     */
    @Override
    public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) {
        SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this).addWindowListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent event) {
    }

//  Implement WindowListener
    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        startScrolling();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        stopScrolling();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        stopScrolling();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        pauseScrolling();    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        resumeScrolling();    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        if (isScrollWhenFocused()) {
            resumeScrolling();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        if (isScrollWhenFocused()) {
            pauseScrolling();
        }
    }
}

public class Main extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

    private JTable  table;
    private DefaultTableModel    model;
    MarqueePanelV mpv = new MarqueePanelV();
    private Timer timer2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        new Main();
    }

    Main() {
        setSize(600, 400);
        this.setLocation(300, 300);
        table = new JTable();
        model = new DefaultTableModel(20, 2);
        table.setModel(model);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(280);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(280);
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            model.setValueAt(i, i, 0);
            model.setValueAt(100 + i, i, 1);
        }
        mpv.add(table);
        add(mpv);
        mpv.setWrap(true);
        mpv.setWrapAmount(0);
        mpv.startScrolling();
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        //  Implement MouseListener
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                mpv.pauseScrolling();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                mpv.resumeScrolling();
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
        timer2 = new Timer(2000, this);
        timer2.setInitialDelay(1000);
        timer2.setDelay(2000);
        timer2.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            model.setValueAt(100 + i, i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely an update from your listener?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), demonstrated a.m. issue, short, runnable, compilable, where value for XxxTableModel.setValueAt should be ganerated from Random

Comment: @mKorbel I have to wait 8 hours to be able to post code here

Comment: *"I have to wait 8 hours to be able to post code here"*  What?!?  SO is not forcing that on you.  BTW - 345 lines of code and still no `main(String[])`?  See the comment of @mKorbel

Comment: @Andrew Thompson   I tried to put the code in an answer to my question and SO said that memebers with no reputation cannot answer to their own question earlier than 8 hours. Where did you see the 345 lines of code? My code has 413 lines, but I don't see it on SO yet.

Comment: *"cannot answer to their own question"*  No, but you should `share` `|` [`edit`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13771143/edit) `| ..` that code *into the question.*  But for better help sooner, post an [**S**SCCE](http://sscce.org/) (i.e. far less than 413 LOC).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by calling mpv.repaint(); in the timer2 action:

```
package scrollingtable;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

class MarqueePanelV extends JPanel
                       implements ActionListener, AncestorListener, WindowListener {
    private boolean paintChildren;
    private boolean scrollingPaused;
    private int scrollOffset;
    private int wrapOffset;
    private int preferredHeight = -1;
    private int scrollAmount;
    private int scrollFrequency;
    private boolean wrap = false;
    private int wrapAmount = 0;
    private boolean scrollWhenFocused = true;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(100, this);

    /**
     *  Convenience constructor that sets both the scroll frequency and
     *  scroll amount to a value of 5.
     */
    public MarqueePanelV() {
        this(20, 1);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param scrollFrequency
     * @param scrollAmount
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("LeakingThisInConstructor")
    public MarqueePanelV(int scrollFrequency, int scrollAmount) {
        setScrollFrequency(scrollFrequency);
        setScrollAmount(scrollAmount);
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        addAncestorListener(this);
    }

    /*
     *  Translate the location of the children before they are painted so it
     *  appears they are scrolling bottom to top
     */
    @Override
    public void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
        //  Need this so we don't see a flicker of the text before scrolling

        if (!paintChildren) {
            return;
        }
        int x = super.getPreferredSize().height;

        //  Normal painting as the components scroll bottom to top

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate(0, -scrollOffset);
        super.paintChildren(g);
        g2d.translate(0, scrollOffset);

        //  Repaint the start of the components on the bottom edge of the panel once
        //  all the components are completely visible on the panel.
        //  (Its like the components are in two places at the same time)

        if (isWrap()) {
            //wrapOffset = scrollOffset - super.getPreferredSize().height - wrapAmount;
            wrapOffset = scrollOffset - x - wrapAmount;
            g2d.translate(0, -wrapOffset);
            super.paintChildren(g);
            g2d.translate(0, wrapOffset);
        }
    }

    /*
     *  The default preferred size will be half the size of the components added to
     *  the panel. This will allow room for components to be scrolled on and off
     *  the panel.
     *
     *  The default height can be overriden by using the setPreferredHeight() method.
     */
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();

        d.height = (preferredHeight == -1) ? d.height / 2 : preferredHeight;

        return d;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return preferredHeight;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the preferred height on the panel. A value of -1 will cause the
     *  default preferred with size calculation to be used.
     *
     *  @param preferredHeight  preferred height of the panel in pixels
     */
    public void setPreferredHeight(int preferredHeight) {
        this.preferredHeight = preferredHeight;
        revalidate();
    }

    /**
     *  Get the scroll amount.
     *
     *  @return the scroll amount in pixels
     */
    public int getScrollAmount() {
        return scrollAmount;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the scroll amount. The number of pixels to scroll every time
     *  scrolling is done.
     *
     *  @param scrollAmount  scroll amount in pixels
     */
    public void setScrollAmount(int scrollAmount) {
        this.scrollAmount = scrollAmount;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the scroll frequency.
     *
     *  @return the scroll frequency
     */
    public int getScrollFrequency() {
        return scrollFrequency;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the scroll frequency. That is the number of times scrolling
     *  should be performed every second.
     *
     *  @param scrollFrequency  scroll frequency
     */
    public void setScrollFrequency(int scrollFrequency) {
        this.scrollFrequency = scrollFrequency;

        int delay = 1000 / scrollFrequency;
        timer.setInitialDelay(delay);
        timer.setDelay(delay);
    }

    /**
     *  Get the scroll only when visible property.
     *
     *  @return the scroll only when visible value
     */
    public boolean isScrollWhenFocused() {
        return scrollWhenFocused;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the scrolling property for unfocused windows.
     *
     *  @param scrollWhenVisible  when true scrolling pauses when the window
     *                                loses focus. Scrolling will continue when
     *                                the window regains focus. When false
     *                                scrolling is continuous unless the window
     *                                is iconified.
     */
    public void setScrollWhenFocused(boolean scrollWhenFocused) {
        this.scrollWhenFocused = scrollWhenFocused;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the wrap property.
     *
     *  @return the wrap value
     */
    public boolean isWrap() {
        return wrap;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the wrapping property. Normal scrolling is such that all the text
     *  will scroll from bottom to top. When the last part of the text scrolls off
     *  the bottom edge scrolling will start again from the bottom edge. Therefore
     *  there is a time when the component is blank as nothing is displayed.
     *  Wrapping implies that as the end of the text scrolls off the top edge
     *  the beginning of the text will scroll in from the bottom edge. So the end
     *  and the start of the text is displayed at the same time.
     *
     *  @param wrap  when true the start of the text will scroll in from the bottom
     *                edge while the end of the text is still scrolling off the top
     *                edge. Otherwise the panel must be clear of text before it
     *                will begin again from the bottom edge.
     */
    public void setWrap(boolean wrap) {
        this.wrap = wrap;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the wrap amount.
     *
     *  @return the wrap amount value
     */
    public int getWrapAmount() {
        return wrapAmount;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the wrapping amount. This specifies the space between the end of the
     *  text on the top edge and the start of the text from the bottom edge when
     *  wrapping is turned on.
     *
     *  @param wrapAmount  the amount in pixels
     */
    public void setWrapAmount(int wrapAmount) {
        this.wrapAmount = wrapAmount;
    }

    /**
     *  Start scrolling the components on the panel. Components will start
     *  scrolling from the bottom edge towards the top edge.
     */
    public void startScrolling() {
        paintChildren = true;
        scrollOffset = -getSize().height;

        timer.start();
    }

    /**
     *  Stop scrolling the components on the panel. The conponents will be
     *  cleared from the view of the panel
     */
    public void stopScrolling() {
        timer.stop();
        paintChildren = false;
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     *  The components will stop scrolling but will remain visible
     */
    public void pauseScrolling() {
        if (timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.stop();
            scrollingPaused = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     *  The components will resume scrolling from where scrolling was stopped.
     */
    public void resumeScrolling() {
        if (scrollingPaused) {
            timer.restart();
            scrollingPaused = false;
        }
    }


    //  Implement ActionListener
    /**
     *  Adjust the offset of the components on the panel so it appears that
     *  they are scrolling from bottom to top.
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        scrollOffset += scrollAmount;
        int height = super.getPreferredSize().height;

        if (scrollOffset > height) {
            scrollOffset = isWrap() ? wrapOffset + scrollAmount : -getSize().height;
        }

        repaint();
    }

    //  Implement AncestorListener
    /**
     *  Get notified when the panel is added to a Window so we can use a
     *  WindowListener to automatically start the scrolling of the components.
     */
    @Override
    public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) {
        SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this).addWindowListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent event) {
    }

    //  Implement WindowListener
    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        startScrolling();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        stopScrolling();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        stopScrolling();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        pauseScrolling();    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        resumeScrolling();    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        if (isScrollWhenFocused()) {
            resumeScrolling();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        if (isScrollWhenFocused()) {
            pauseScrolling();
        }
    }

}

public class Main extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

    private JTable  table;
    private DefaultTableModel    model;
    MarqueePanelV mpv = new MarqueePanelV();
    private Timer timer2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        new Main();
    }

    Main() {
        setSize(600, 400);
        this.setLocation(300, 300);
        table = new JTable();
        model = new DefaultTableModel(20, 2);
        table.setModel(model);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(280);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(280);
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            model.setValueAt(i, i, 0);
            model.setValueAt(100 + i, i, 1);
        }
        mpv.add(table);
        add(mpv);
        mpv.setWrap(true);
        mpv.setWrapAmount(0);
        mpv.startScrolling();
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        //  Implement MouseListener
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                mpv.pauseScrolling();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                mpv.resumeScrolling();
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
        timer2 = new Timer(2000, this);
        timer2.setInitialDelay(1000);
        timer2.setDelay(2000);
        timer2.start();
    }

    int k = 0;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            model.setValueAt(100 + i + k, i, 1);
        }
        k++;
        mpv.repaint();
    }
}
```